# Java Applet not displaying completely in AppletViewer

Tags: java, applet, bluej, appletviewer, stalled

I'm building a calculator applet that isn't displaying about half the code within the AppletViewer.

I'm using BlueJ (as required by my teacher) and the code compiles just fine, albeit, with a noticeable lag as compared to when I first started writing the program. When attempting to run in AppletViewer, only about the first half of code runs, but I never receive an error message. The status just stays at "Executing Applet in AppletViewer".

Within the code, I have methods that call other methods within more methods. I have multiple loops and arrays occurring for displaying the content and more variables then I can count.

I have tested individual methods in separate project files as I wrote them, before adding them to the actual project, so I'm fairly certain each component works in and of itself. It's only when I put them all together that things start displaying incorrectly.

Because of this, I'm wondering if I've simply put in too much content, bogged down the system. If so, is there a way increase the threshold, and how would I implement it?

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The culprit lay in the last array set I was working with. A simple "<=" was causing an "array index out of range" error, despite no error message being displayed.